# How to prove the following matrices inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices $(nxn)$. How can we prove the following inequality?

[image]

-->An OPINION: One friend disserts it is false.  His counter-example is:

$n=4$, $B=2I_4$, $A=I_4$, and $\|M\|=\max_{\|x\|_2=1} \frac{\|Mx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$.
Then $(A+B)^n-A^n=(3^n-1) I_4$. So, $\|(A+B)^n-A^n\|=3^4-1$.

And $\|B\|\|A\|^{n-1}e^{\frac{\|B\|}{\|A\|}}=2e^2<3^4-1$.

What do you think?

Comment: One can endow the space of matrices with several norms; which one do you mean to use? The "operatorial norm", used by your friend?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of [I need help proving a matrix norm inequality]...

Comment: @AlexM. Unfortunaltely, our teacher didn' t say which norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend is right. His counter-example works.